# Recursive Sierpinski carpet using turtle graphics

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

This question is based on python recursion. This should be done with degree = 4, so 4 different levels of boxes. My issue is that with the code I have already, it did not draw well for the other degrees. Please let me know what I have done wrong, below is my code where I used to get all my values woking.

```
import turtle


def drawboxes(points, color, myTurtle):
    myTurtle.fillcolor(color)
    myTurtle.up()  # Pen up
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    myTurtle.down()  # Pen down
    myTurtle.begin_fill()
    myTurtle.goto(points[1][0], points[1][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[2][0], points[2][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[3][0], points[3][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    myTurtle.end_fill()

def getMid1(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3)

def getMid2(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3 * 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3 * 2)

def getMid3(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3 * 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3)

def getMid4(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3 * 2)

def getMid5(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3, p1[1] + p2[1])

def getMid6(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 3 * 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]))

def getMid7(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]), (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3 * 2)

def getMid8(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]), (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 3)

def sierpinski(points, degree, myTurtle):
    colormap = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'cyan', 'yellow',
                'violet', 'orange']

    drawboxes(points,colormap[degree], myTurtle)

    if degree > 0:
        sierpinski([points[0],
                getMid1(points[0], points[1]),
                getMid1(points[0], points[2]),
                getMid1(points[0], points[3])],
               degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid1(points[0], points[1]),
                getMid2(points[0], points[1]),
                getMid4(points[0], points[2]),
                getMid1(points[0], points[2])],
               degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([points[1],
                    getMid2(points[0], points[1]),
                    getMid4(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid5(points[1], points[3])],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid5(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid4(points[0], points[2]),
                    getMid2(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid6(points[1], points[3])],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid2(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid6(points[1], points[3]),
                    points[2],
                    getMid7(points[1], points[3])],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid3(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid2(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid7(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid8(points[1], points[3])],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid2(points[0], points[3]),
                    getMid3(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid8(points[1], points[3]),
                    points[3]],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([getMid1(points[0], points[3]),
                    getMid1(points[0], points[2]),
                    getMid3(points[1], points[3]),
                    getMid2(points[0], points[3])],
                   degree - 1, myTurtle)


def main():
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.speed(10)  # adjust the drawing speed here
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    # 3 points of the first triangle based on [x,y] coordinates
    myPoints = [[0, 0], [0, 300], [300, 300], [300, 0]]
    degree = 1  # Vary the degree of complexity here
    # first call of the recursive function
    sierpinski(myPoints, degree, myTurtle)

    myTurtle.hideturtle()  # hide the turtle cursor after drawing is
# completed
    myWin.exitonclick()  # Exit program when user click on window


main()
```

Comment: I slowdowned it to see how it works and understand where can be problem but I don't know. Long time ago I made own version but I see it works different and it is much smaller: [furas/python-examples/turtle/sierpinski-carpet](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/turtle/sierpinski-carpet) I don't calculate points to draw rectangles but lengths which I use with `forward()` and  `left()/right()`

Comment: so only way is to debug it in some way. You can slowdown it at some moment and display values in variables. Maybe it helps to see problem. Maybe some value is rounded too much or

Answer (score 0):

Some of your calculations works correctly only when P1 is (0,0) but gives wrong results when P1 is different.

For `getMid1` you have

```
 X = (A + B)/3
```

which for `A=0, B=3` gives correct result

```
 X = (0 + 3)/3 = 1
```

It is point in 1/3 of distance between A and B

But for A=1, B=2 gives

```
 X = (1 + 2)/3 = 1
```

so it gives `X=A` but correct values is `X=1+(1/3)`

Correct results give formula

```
 X = A + ((B - A)/3)
```

or

```
 X = A + (1/3 * (B-A))
```

Similar formulas should be for other points but I didn't check it yet.

```
 X = A + (0/3 * (B-A)) # = A
 X = A + (1/3 * (B-A)) 
 X = A + (2/3 * (B-A))
 X = A + (3/3 * (B-A)) # = B
```

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

Using my formulas I created working code.

But I reduced code to one function `get()` instead of eight `getMid1` ... `getMid8`. It uses `V`, `H` to calculate `V/3`, `H/3` (`0/3`, `1/3`, `2/3`, `3/3`)

```
def get(p1, p2, V, H, show=False): # Vertical, Horizontal
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2

    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    new_x = x1 + V/3 * dx
    new_y = y1 + H/3 * dy

    if show:
        print('NEW:', new_x, new_y)

    return new_x, new_y
```

In calculations I also use only `points[0], points[2]` because I can find in `points[0], points[2]` values which are in `points[1], points[3]`

Full code:

```
import turtle

def drawTriangle(points, color, myTurtle, show=False):
    if show:
        print('DRAW:', points)

    myTurtle.fillcolor(color)
    myTurtle.up()  # Pen up
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    myTurtle.down()  # Pen down
    myTurtle.begin_fill()
    myTurtle.goto(points[1][0], points[1][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[2][0], points[2][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[3][0], points[3][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    myTurtle.end_fill()


def get(p1, p2, V, H, show=False): # Vertical, Horizontal
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2

    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    new_x = x1 + V/3 * dx
    new_y = y1 + H/3 * dy

    if show:
        print('NEW:', new_x, new_y)

    return new_x, new_y


def sierpinski(points, degree, myTurtle):

    colormap = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'cyan', 'yellow',
                'violet', 'orange']

    # Draw a triangle based on the 3 points given
    drawTriangle(points, colormap[degree], myTurtle)

    if degree > 0:
        #print('--- 1 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 0),
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 0)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 2 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 1)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 3 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 0, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 2)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 4 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 2)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 5 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 3),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 2)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 6 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 2),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 1)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 7 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 0),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 3, 0)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)

        #print('--- 8 ---')
        #print(points)
        sierpinski([
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 0),
                get(points[0], points[2], 1, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 1),
                get(points[0], points[2], 2, 0)
               ], degree-1, myTurtle)


def main():
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.speed(0)  # adjust the drawing speed here
    myWin = turtle.Screen()

    size = 300
    # 3 points of the first triangle based on [x,y] coordinates
    myPoints = [[0, 0], [0, size], [size, size], [size, 0]]

    degree = 3  # Vary the degree of complexity here

    # first call of the recursive function
    sierpinski(myPoints, degree, myTurtle)

    myTurtle.hideturtle()  # hide the turtle cursor after drawing is completed
    myWin.exitonclick()  # Exit program when user click on window


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your calling four cornered shapes *"triangles"*.  Moving on:

I believe the problem with your code is how you determine the origin for each recursion -- as written, the code is returning to absolute (0, 0) more often than it should.  To understand your code, I tore it apart and put it back together again.  But it's now a very different beast.  I called on turtle's `Vec2D` to manipulate postions as a whole, not operate on their X and Y coordinates separately.  And I replaced your block of eight recursive calls with a loop:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

COLOR_MAP = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'violet', 'orange']

def drawRectangle(points, color, myTurtle):
    myTurtle.fillcolor(color)

    myTurtle.begin_fill()

    for point in points:
        myTurtle.goto(point)

    myTurtle.goto(points[0])

    myTurtle.end_fill()

def sierpinski(points, degree, myTurtle):

    """ Draw a rectangle based on the 4 points given """

    drawRectangle(points, COLOR_MAP[degree % len(COLOR_MAP)], myTurtle)

    if degree > 0:
        origin = points[0] * (2 / 3)  # vectors multiply by a scalar, but not divide

        points = [point * (1 / 3) for point in points]  # new rectangle is 1/3 size of old rectangle

        width, height = points[2] - points[0]  # vector subtraction

        for y in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                if x == 1 == y:
                    continue  # leave hole in the center

                offset = origin + Vec2D(width * x, height * y)

                sierpinski([offset + point for point in points], degree - 1, myTurtle)

def main():
    # 4 points of the first rectangle based on [x, y] coordinates
    POINTS = [Vec2D(0, 0), Vec2D(0, 300), Vec2D(300, 300), Vec2D(300, 0)]

    myWin = Screen()
    myWin.tracer(False)

    myTurtle = Turtle()
    myTurtle.penup()

    degree = 3  # Vary the degree of complexity here
    # first call of the recursive function
    sierpinski(POINTS, degree, myTurtle)

    myTurtle.hideturtle()  # hide turtle cursor after drawing is completed

    myWin.tracer(True)
    myWin.exitonclick()  # Exit program when user click on window

main()
```

[image]

I realize that this isn't code you can incorporate directly, but hopefully some of the ideas will be helpful as well as being able to print and compare positions.